# Circle containing text in python-pptx

Tags: powerpoint, openxml, python-pptx

I would like to draw a circle shape - always with text in. Sometimes this circle will be filled, sometimes not.

How should I approach this?

I'm familiar with `MSO_SHAPE` - having used `CHEVRON` to similar effect before. I see `ARC` but don't know if I can get that to close. I also see `ROUNDED_RECTANGLE` but doubt I can control the radius. I also see `OVAL` - which might well be my best bet.

If necessary I can get down into the XML - hence my tagging this with OpenXML also - but hope not to have to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is `MSO_SHAPE.OVAL` with the height and width the same. It makes a nice circle.